# Show/Hide an accordion panel in Jquery when clicking edit in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery Accordion and I have a asp.net GridView below that.  When I click on the edit button in a gridview row, it goes and grabs some data.  Depending on which row is clicked, I want to show/hide an accordion panel.  Can I accomplish this in the GridView_RowEditing event, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
(Me.GetType(), "ClientScript", "$(document).ready(function(){$('#accordion').accordion('activate', parseInt(theIndex));}", True)
```

So, I haven't tried this, but it seems like it should work.  But you might have to play with it a little, theIndex will need to variable passed in from the grid row.

Comment: When i get a chance, I will give it a shot.  Thanks!